# How can I preview PDFs with Google Chrome in dark mode?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, pdf, color-theme

How can I preview PDFs with  Google Chrome in dark mode / reverse color?

By default it is white colored:

[image: Screenshot showing question author looking at arxiv.org research archive PDF, in Google Chrome]

Followed-up by my asking [How can I change the grey background of the PDF preview in Google Chrome to black?](https://superuser.com/questions/1527577/how-can-i-change-the-grey-background-of-the-pdf-preview-in-google-chrome-to-blac).

Comment: Chrome is not part of Windows, why did you tag it Windows?

Comment: @Mark in case of OS-dependent solution.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

##### The following snippet adds a `div` overlay to any browser tab currently displaying a PDF document.

###### 1. Open up your browser's Dev tools then browser console.

###### 2. Paste this JavaScript code in your browser console:

```
const overlay = document.createElement("div");

const css = `
    position: fixed;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    z-index: 1;
`
overlay.setAttribute("style", css);

document.body.appendChild(overlay);
```

###### 3. Hit `Enter`

Special thanks: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/e3txhi/comment/fem1cto

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up question: [How can I change the grey background of the PDF preview in Google Chrome to black?](https://superuser.com/q/1527577/116475)

Comment: Tip: This seemst o work for more than PDFs!

Comment: Perfect! This works for all kinds of things! I changed the css a little bit `opacity: .5; background-color: #67645e` - even better!

Comment: made a simple [Chrome extension](https://github.com/amar567/chrome_pdf_dark-mode) form answer by @programmer365

Comment: Thank you very much. Really love this solution been using it for a while now. Is there a way to save/print the pdf using (maintaining) this dark theme?

Comment: @DougieT the dark theme applies to the browser, not the PDF itself, so if you can use an extension based on this code to keep it permanently (like the one bingo provided in commnets). thanks for using it!

Answer (score 20):

You can use the [Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en-US) Google Chrome extension and used the `Filter+` mode. It will work on the online PDF files, but not at the local PDF files.

**Hint from Hirbot Behnam:** 
If you want to make it work with **local files** (e.g. PDFs) too, go to chrome://extensions/ and click on Details button below the extension "Dark Reader" and from there, enable Allow access to file URLs.

[image]

Comment: it works, thank you!

Comment: If you want to make it work with local files too, go to `chrome://extensions/` and click on Details button below the extension and from there, enable `Allow access to file URLs`.

Comment: This did not work for me when opening local pdfs

Comment: @MaLiN2223 Correct, this doesn't work when opening local pdfs, which is quite annoying.

Comment: I tried using this option on Firefox, and it also does not work on online pdfs. It says that the website is protected...

Comment: This did work for me, including for local PDF when allowing access to file URLs in Chrome Extensions settings.