# How can I change the grey background of the PDF preview in Google Chrome to black?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, pdf, color-theme

How can I change the grey background of the PDF preview in Google Chrome to black?

For example, on https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.06394.pdf:

[image: PDF in Google Chrome, showing visual state]

using [this code](https://superuser.com/a/1527417/116475) in the console (and disabling the [Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en-US) Google Chrome extension if it was enabled):

```
var cover = document.createElement("div");
let css = `
    position: fixed;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    z-index: 1;
`
cover.setAttribute("style", css);
document.body.appendChild(cover);
```

I can make the white background black:

[image: Google Chrome PDF preview function, with Google Chrome Extension called Dark Reader]

However, the background of the PDF preview in Google Chrome is still grey. Instead I would like something such as:

[image: Custom rendering of ideal setting required by question asker, is not a real browser example, rendering was made in a graphics manipulation program.]

*Following my asking [How can I preview PDFs with Google Chrome in dark mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/1527410/how-can-i-preview-pdfs-with-google-chrome-in-dark-mode), now asking about changing the design for the rest of the screen.*

Comment: That background you want to change is not a part of the document but the gray part of the document reader itself. I am not clear on how Chrome or Windows would handle that, but it is literally “outside of the box” of what PDF adjustments can handle.

Comment: @JakeGould I agree.

Comment: How about this plugin? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-colors/ageghplgcapnfpdhapeemolbmfccclke

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get the pdf to look the way you want it using Microsoft Edge. If you have Edge in light mode the background of the PDF viewer will be white. By inverting the colors with the code you pasted/using an extension (like Dark Reader), the result you describe can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

### *Zoom in* to *Full Page* width, or change *Window Size*, so PDF reaches edge (with [Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en-US) from your question):

For example, on https://www.gao.gov/assets/gao-19-221.pdf [(*)](https://web.archive.org/web/0/https://www.gao.gov/assets/gao-19-221.pdf):
[image: Zoom with Dark Reader Google Chrome Extension]
***Now you still have the "gray color border" imposed by Google Chrome (whose bright idea was that, was it a full thought? We can blame trees for white paper.), but you're not forced to take that as the full version.***

Ideally being a Black background would be obvious, computer code would enable us to disable these unconsciously scripted forms to be self-edited, it's not just a form of accessibility, it's about designing to be accessible in the lowest code logic.

Comment: Why blame trees for white paper? Paper that isn't bleached isn't white, right?

Comment: @Gantendo Good, you grok` the point. (To be normative, we'd just wholly blame Google Chrome. Sound bites for logic, right? I mean in this case we could probably dictate Operating System level changes, if developers and companies do not wish to comply then changing the low level code is really the option we do not talk about, I mean that's a Level required for most surveillance to work but we do not talk about opting-in a social const, where Users and Superusers want to wear the full Batman/Batwoman spandex gear, including wearing our own costume customization settings, required by a User Law?)